# Magento 2: Error on reindex

Tags: magento2, error, products, reindex, indexer

I have recently upgrade my instance from Magento 2.3.0 to 2.4.3 and products are not showing on the frontend. When I run php bin/magento indexer:reindex command I get this error:
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If error in indexing after upgrade then run below sql query in phpmyadmin

> CREATE  SQL SECURITY INVOKER   VIEW `inventory_stock_1`   AS  SELECT
> DISTINCT    legacy_stock_status.product_id,
> legacy_stock_status.website_id,   legacy_stock_status.stock_id,
> legacy_stock_status.qty quantity,   legacy_stock_status.stock_status
> is_salable,   product.sku    FROM cataloginventory_stock_status legacy_stock_status `INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity` product
> ON legacy_stock_status.product_id = product.entity_id;

and run below commands

- Clear `var/generation`
- Clear `var/cache`
- Enable Magento modules: `php bin/magento module:enable --all`
- Compile DI `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

now run below commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```